# Is there a way for monkeyrunner to look at call and sms history on a device?

Tags: android, sqlite, monkeyrunner

Is there a way for me to have monkeyrunner be able to look at call and sms history without using sqlite3? Before, I was using Popen with `adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts*.db 'select * from calls'"` and while that works on emulators it does not work on non rooted devices.

Is there a way to do something similar without rooting the device?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using monkeyrunner startActivity, broadcastIntent. I believe using broadcastIntent you can actually call a activity like launching com.android.contacts/.DialtactsActivity

Comment: yeah, but that's not going to give you a dump of the contacts database, which is what I was asking about.